# Why is this integral throwing a "MemoryAllocationFailure" error?

Tags: numerical-integration, warning-messages, precision-and-accuracy

The following call to `NIntegrate` throws the error:

> Throw::sysexc: Uncaught SystemException returned to top level. Can be caught with Catch[[Ellipsis], _SystemException].

and returns `SystemException["MemoryAllocationFailure"]` as output.

```
NIntegrate[
 PolyLog[-3, -E^(-(Sqrt[a (k^2 + 1)] - 1/2)/T)] Sec[x]^2 /. {k -> 
    1/100 Tan[x], T -> 1/1000, a -> 27/100}, {x, 0, \[Pi]/2}, 
 PrecisionGoal -> 12]
```

Meanwhile, adding additionally `WorkingPrecision->20` causes the evaluation to last too long and results in a kernel crash.

Any ideas what the root problem is and how to fix this? I really would like to evaluate this integral to many digits of precision (the issue goes away at lower precision), and I'm looking for a reliable way to calculate many integrals of this type with slightly different parameter values.

Comment: Try using WorkingPrecision->200 instead.

Comment: NIntegrate seems not to be able to calculate the integral with exact numbers. But it gives an answer if you change some constants to machine numbers.

Comment: Simplify the integrand: `NIntegrate[PolyLog[-3, -E^(-(Sqrt[a (k^2 + 1)] - 1/2)/T)] Sec[x]^2 /. {k -> 1/100 Tan[x], T -> 1/1000, a -> 27/100} // Simplify, {x, 0, \[Pi]/2}, WorkingPrecision -> 20]`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! They work. @CarlWoll any idea why *increasing* WorkingPrecision avoids issues involved with memory overload? I would have thought that would make things worse?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what might be needed in other integrals, but for this one, `MinRecursion -> 3` seems to work at various precision goals:

```
Table[
 NIntegrate[
  PolyLog[-3, -E^(-(Sqrt[a (k^2 + 1)] - 1/2)/T)] Sec[x]^2 /. {k -> 
     1/100 Tan[x], T -> 1/1000, a -> 27/100}, {x, 0, π/2}, 
  PrecisionGoal -> pg, MinRecursion -> 3, 
  Method -> {"GlobalAdaptive", 
    Method -> {"GaussKronrodRule", "Points" -> 21}, 
    "SymbolicProcessing" -> None}, WorkingPrecision -> 2 pg],
 {pg, {12, 16, 30}}]
(*
{-1.66625181179756853846696*10^-8, \
-1.6662518117975685384669577064196*10^-8, \
-1.66625181179756853846695769835962377225227776502356624286066*10^-8}
*)
```

It works at machine precision, too:

```
NIntegrate[
 PolyLog[-3, -E^(-(Sqrt[a (k^2 + 1)] - 1/2)/T)] Sec[x]^2 /. {k -> 
    1/100 Tan[x], T -> 1/1000, a -> 27/100}, {x, 0, π/2}, 
 PrecisionGoal -> 12, MinRecursion -> 3]
```

Local adaptive integration works, too:

```
NIntegrate[
 PolyLog[-3, -E^(-(Sqrt[a (k^2 + 1)] - 1/2)/T)] Sec[x]^2 /. {k -> 
    1/100 Tan[x], T -> 1/1000, a -> 27/100}, {x, 0, π/2}, 
 PrecisionGoal -> 12, Method -> "LocalAdaptive"]
```

*Update:*
Yet another fix (suggests bad numerics near `Pi/2`):

```
NIntegrate[
 PolyLog[-3, -E^(-(Sqrt[a (k^2 + 1)] - 1/2)/T)] Sec[x]^2 /. 
  {k -> 1/100 Tan[x], T -> 1/1000, a -> 27/100},
 {x, 0, π/2 - 0.01, π/2}, PrecisionGoal -> 12]
```

---

**Analysis and discussion**

The first thing to do when something goes wrong is to plot the integrand (note that `Dt[100 k] == Sec[x]^2 Dt[x]` -- makes me wonder about the `100`):

```
plot = Plot[PolyLog[-3, -E^(-(Sqrt[a (k^2 + 1)] - 1/2)/T)] Dt[100 k] /.
     {k -> 1/100 Tan[x], T -> 1/1000, a -> 27/100} /. Dt[x] -> 1 // 
  Evaluate, {x, 0, \[Pi]/2}]
```

[image]

Shortly after `x == 1.5` the curve flattens dramatically, which caught my attention.  In fact, there's some sort of underflow:

```
Cases[plot, Line[p_] :> Drop[p[[All, 2]], {10, -13}], Infinity]
(*
{{-3.02837*10^-9, -3.02854*10^-9, -3.02907*10^-9, -3.02925*10^-9, 
  -3.02946*10^-9, -3.02969*10^-9, -3.02994*10^-9, -3.03022*10^-9, 
  -3.03051*10^-9,
  ...,
  -6.103*10^-125, -2.84532*10^-138, -6.38854*10^-154, -1.20053*10^-194,
   0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.}}
*)
```

The OP's issue is certainly connected to this.  Another tool to use is `NIntegrateSamplingPoints`.  We'll reduce the `AccuracyGoal` in the OP's integral to less than `16`, so that the integration will terminate without error.

```
Needs["Integration`NIntegrateUtilities`"]
NIntegrateSamplingPoints[
 NIntegrate[
  PolyLog[-3, -E^(-(Sqrt[a (k^2 + 1)] - 1/2)/T)] Dt[100 k] /.
    {k -> 1/100 Tan[x], T -> 1/1000, a -> 27/100} /. Dt[x] -> 1,
  {x, 0, \[Pi]/2}, PrecisionGoal -> 12, AccuracyGoal -> 15]
 ]
```

[image]

One can see the sampling clustering around `x == 1.5` for the last hundred sampling points.  Something seems to happen to the sampling when the sampling gets above 100.  Below it, we see the typical Gauss-Kronrod sampling patterns; also at the top.  Something special seems to be happening around `1.5`, but I'm not sure what that is.  My guess is that the extra sampling gets out of hand in the OP's integral (in which the default `AccuracyGoal` is `Infinity`).  Note that we cannot use `AccuracyGoal -> 15` to achieve the OP's aims, since an accuracy of 15 places past the decimal point in a result around `10^-8` is only around 7 digits of relative precision.

`NIntegrateSamplingPoints` also reveals what happens with `WorkingPrecision -> 200` (@CarlWoll's suggestion).  The normal default method uses Gauss-Kronrod with 5 Gauss points and 6 Kronrod points (it's always `n` and `n+1`).  But for high precision integrations, this is increased and depends on the precision.  The increase can be seen in the sampling plot:

```
Needs["Integration`NIntegrateUtilities`"]
NIntegrateSamplingPoints[
 NIntegrate[
  PolyLog[-3, -E^(-(Sqrt[a (k^2 + 1)] - 1/2)/T)] Dt[100 k] /.
    {k -> 1/100 Tan[x], T -> 1/1000, a -> 27/100} /. Dt[x] -> 1,
  {x, 0, \[Pi]/2}, PrecisionGoal -> 12, WorkingPrecision -> 200]
 ]
```

[image]

There are five GK samplings, and we can deduce that the number of Gauss points is 66:

```
Count[%, _Point, Infinity]/5.
(% - 1)/2
(*
  133.
  66.
*)
```

This suggests that we could use the GK method with `"Points" -> 66`, which we can even at machine precision:

```
NIntegrate[
 PolyLog[-3, -E^(-(Sqrt[a (k^2 + 1)] - 1/2)/T)] Dt[100 k] /.
   {k -> 1/100 Tan[x], T -> 1/1000, a -> 27/100} /. Dt[x] -> 1,
 {x, 0, \[Pi]/2}, PrecisionGoal -> 12, 
 Method -> {"GaussKronrodRule", "Points" -> 66}]

(*  -1.66625*10^-8  *)
```

**A better substitution?**

Finally, the issue is introduce by the tangent transformation `k -> 1/100 Tan[x]`.  We could look for another one that doesn't have the flattening out around `1.5`.  A logarithmic one seems likely to be what we want.

```
Plot[PolyLog[-3, -E^(-(Sqrt[a (k^2 + 1)] - 1/2)/T)] Dt[100 k] /.
    {k -> 1/100 Log[1 + x/(1 - x)^2],   (* new transformation *)
     T -> 1/1000, a -> 27/100} /. Dt[x] -> 1 // Evaluate,
 {x, 0, 1}]      (* different interval for new transformation *)
```

[image]

This produces an integral without issues:

```
NIntegrate[
 PolyLog[-3, -E^(-(Sqrt[a (k^2 + 1)] - 1/2)/T)] Dt[100 k] /.
     {k -> 1/100 Log[1 + x/(1 - x)^2],
      T -> 1/1000, a -> 27/100} /. Dt[x] -> 1 // Evaluate,
 {x, 0, 1}, PrecisionGoal -> 12]

(*  -1.66625*10^-8  *)
```

Comment: Thanks for these strategies. I'm going to try implementing them to see if they work on the numerous generic integrals of similar form that I am dealing with.

Comment: @WillG I added some more alternatives.